# How to add Digicert SSL certificate to Kubernetes Secrets in GCP?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate

I have a digicert SSL cert that I want to install in GCP secrets and reference it to one of the ingress resources. Currently have four files

```
privatekey.pem
{domain-name.crt}
DigiCertca.crt
Trustedroot.crt
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can kubernetes cert-manager import existing certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71348876/can-kubernetes-cert-manager-import-existing-certificate)

Comment: I tried to do the same - but i also have the digicertca.crt, do i need to copy it with the domain-name.crt ?

Comment: You do not need the CA file -- just the pem and the certificate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Blender Fox posted in the comment, in the cluster, you can import already-issued certificates.

Use `--from-file` or `--from-env-file` to generate a Secret from one or more files. The file must be in plaintext format; it is unimportant what extension it has.

The command states:

```
kubectl create secret SECRET_TYPE SECRET_NAME
  --from-file PATH_TO_FILE1 
  --from-file PATH_TO_FILE2
```

Change the *PATH_TO_FILE1* and *PATH_TO_FILE2* in your case to the appropriate *.pem* and *.crt* files, like @Blender Fox indicated.

Or

If they are in a directory;

```
kubectl create secret SECRET_TYPE SECRET_NAME \
  --from-file PATH_TO_DIRECTORY
```

How to build secrets from files is described in GCP [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/secret#creating_secrets_from_files).